# ValidateEntitySecurity failed on multitenant BSC installation

Tags: 2010, bcs, multi-tenancy

I've got a multitenant BCS service setup. It all seems to work; I've imported my model and it properly lists the entities in the model. But when I try to create an external list based on the model, the picker doesn't list any entities. Upon opening the picker, I notice the following lines in my ULS logs:

ValidateEntitySecurity failed for entity: Customer

Ok, so apparantly there's a security issue. But I've checked the permissions in the BCS config, even granted full rights to everyone just to be sure. So on all the places I know I can configure things, I did. But still there's a security error and now I'm not sure why any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly this had something to do with my site subscriptions not being setup correctly. After recreating it started working. I do have a new problem though: it seems BCS models of type DotNetAssembly aren't allowed in a partitioned BCS service. Crap.